# Very Few Answered Questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-statistics

It seems that at 2012-03-09 15:20 we had -137% of our questions answered. That's a little less than I would have expected, considering I have answered at least one!
[image: "Site Stats: 4,323 questions; 9,546 answers; -137% answered; 1,002 users; 785 visitors/day"]

Comment: Where do you see -137%?

Comment: @IsaacMoses In the picture...

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I can't see imgur pictures at work without doing a little trick. Anyway, it looks like the problem has cleared up now, right?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I suppose. Status-norepo then. But it might be interesting to see what caused it.

Comment: Perhaps you should change it to "It seems that at YYMMDD HHMM, we had -137% ..."

Comment: @IsaacMoses Adjusted. Do you have any better ideas for tags?

Comment: I saw that it said that we had only four answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Our site stats use the [public api](http://api.stackexchange.com) to get their data.  We recently converted this from v1 of the api to v2.

This introduced a bug, which has since been fixed.